# How to get covered areas in image, any algorithm?

Tags: algorithm, shapes, lines, points

[image]

I have an image like in the left side. I want to get covered areas or the arc points of polygons for getting image like in the right side. I have got end point-values of all lines.

How can I do that (get all covered areas)? Any algorithm or ideas?

Comment: this might be better on http://math.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way to do this is with a recursive fill technique.

Assuming you have a black and white image to start with, you drop a pixel of color on one region. You recursively fill the areas to the up, down, left, and right of that pixel. When each of those pixels returns (because all surrounding pixels are colored or black for wall) you return.

You can do this iteratively for each x,y coordinate, skipping it if it's already colord by a previous run. In doing this, you can iterate over colors as well, if you so desire.

Comment: Actually what I want is, getting the closed areas from the line points. For ex, get a line, take first point, and go on to second point of that line, in the second turn, starting from first line's second point, find another line whose first point is first line's second. iterating like this, if we finally get our first point, we have one closed areas. but we must be attentive about getting lines from angle point. all double lines in each iterate should be in the same side for not getting multiple areas in one iteration. So i think that there could be some algorithms.

Answer (score 0):

This is a classic case of binary image segmentation, as far as I can see in the limited resolution of the input image. Invert your image, maybe erode it to fill holes in your lines, and then do an image segmentation. A trivial algorithm for this is to perform a forward scan of the image and assigning each pixel the region value of its backward (directly left or any above direction) white neighbours, or a new region value if it has only black backward neighbours, joining regions when there are neighbours with different region numbers.

Comment: But I don't want to get second image from pixel values. I want to get from line points (I already have points of all lines), Efficiency is important in my case.

Answer (score 0):

As a second approach, if you have a list of unbroken lines, you might try a graph approach. Consider each line as an edge in a graph, and each intersection point as a node, and find the minimal cycles in the graph. These are your rooms.